# getting error method send keys is undefined for the type webelement

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, sendkeys

My code:

```
driver.findElements(By.id("email")).sendKeys("");
```

`.sendkeys` method is not appearing and getting error

> getting error method send keys is undefined for the type webelement

Comment: i think you can try `driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("")` and not `findElements`, https://www.guru99.com/find-element-selenium.html

Answer (score 1):

### sendKeys()

As per the documentation [`sendKeys()`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#sendKeys-java.lang.CharSequence...-) method is used to simulate typing into an **element**, which may set its value.

As per your code trials:

```
driver.findElements(By.id("email"));
```

Would return a *List* and you can't invoke `sendKeys()` on a *List*.

---

### Solution

You need to replace `findElements()` with `findElement()` which would return an element on which you can invoke `sendKeys()`. So effectively your line of code will be:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("");
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be findelement in singular not elements in plural